# Read data attribute from popover

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I need to read a data value conteined into a  from a bootstrap popver.

Details:

There is a popover associated to a panel.
Into the popover there is a link that fires (by onClick) a function that have to read the value of the attribute data-info contained into the panel div.

HTML code:

```
<div class="panel panel-success redim" data-info="informations" data-content="&lt;div onClick=&quot;modifica_appuntamento()&quot; class=&quot;text-center&quot;&gt;&lt;a href=&quot;#&quot;&gt;Get info&lt;/a&gt;&lt;/div&gt;" data-original-title="Get data from popover">
      <div class="panel-heading">Heading</div>
      <div class="panel-body">Body</div>
</div>
```

Jquery:

```
$(function() {
popoverOptions = {
html: true,
animation: true
};
$('.panel').popover(popoverOptions);
});

function modifica_appuntamento() {
  alert($(this).parent().data('info'));
}
```

JSFiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/fabioravizzotti/3h4vu8Ly/

Can you help me to find a solution?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**First problem**:

Your element selector is wrong, as `.parent()` in that case is actually the main `.popover` div and the element you're trying to get `data-info` from is `.prev()`. So you should use:

```
$(this).closest('.popover').prev().data('info');
```

**Second problem**:

You cannot use `$(this)` inside your function. Using inline `onclick` attribute you should pass the element to the function :

```
onClick='modifica_appuntamento(this);'
```

then:

```
function modifica_appuntamento(elem) {
    $(elem)....
}
```

---

On a side note.
[It's not a good practice to use javascript attributes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5871640/why-is-using-onclick-in-html-a-bad-practice)
I'd suggest you to add a `class="data-info"` to the popover links and delegate click event with jQuery:

```
$(document).on('click', '.data-info', function(){
    alert($(this).closest('.popover').prev().data('info'));
});
```

<kbd>[**JSFiddle Demo**](https://jsfiddle.net/3h4vu8Ly/5/)</kbd>

Comment: Hi Artur, it works, sorry but I'm a newbie on javascript. I don't understand how you can use _.popover_ selector in closest function. A class called "popover" there is not into HTML. You get it from bootstrap template? Thanks.

Comment: `.popover` is created dynamically by bootstrap when a *popover* appears (it's the main popover DIV)